# Telnet session with tablet

Tags: telnet, windows-tabletpc

I have a very old legacy application that we want to access thru a tablet. The app is only accesible thru a VT220 telnet session. I'm pretty shure it will work out of the box with Win7, putty and connected with wifi to the local network, like the current setup on desktop PC.

But i don't know about the "user experience". The user must use the keyboard and funktion keys too.

Will that work with an onscreen touchpad keyboard ?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the touchscreen keypad supports the appropriate keys (ctrl, esc etc..) for the system you need to access, or you can send them from a menu pick on the terminal program, there is no reason it shouldn't work. I access several remote systems by terminal from an android tablet without much issue. As for the user experience, that's subjective. I find it good enough for occasional use, less so for everyday as using the keyboard on the tablet can be a bit awkward due to size and feedback constraints.